# Extreme value theory - weak convergence of $P_{a_n^{-1}(X-b_n)}$

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

$(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}},X $ are iid random variables, an it is $M_n=\bigvee X_i$.
If there are $a_n>0$ and $b_n's$, such that $a_n^{-1}(M_n-b_n)$ converges weakly to A (or in distribution) it follows, that $$F(a_nx+b_n) \rightarrow 1 \text{ for every } x \text{ such that } G(x)>0,\text{means for every } x>x_0$$ where $F$ is the distribution function of $X$, and $G$ of $A$, $x_0$ the left endpoint of $G$, means: $x_0:=\inf\left\{x|G(x)>0\right\}$ and so $G(x)=0$ for all $x \leq x_0$.

My Question: Does also follow:

$$ \mu_n \rightarrow \epsilon_{x_0},$$

where $\mu_n$ is the distribution of $a_n^{-1}(X-b_n)$ and $\epsilon_{x_0}$ the dirac measure in $x_0$.